# How to install GCC for Go on Windows 10?

Tags: .net, go, gcc, cygwin

I want to use external library on Go programming language and i am using this command for instance :

```
go get github.com/alecthomas/gozmq
```

from command line, but it gives such an error:

github.com/pebbe/zmq4
exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%

i tried to install Cygwin, but it doesn't fixed the error

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin setup as default installs only a minimal set of packages, the core ones.
If you need additional one as a compiler you need to specifically require it

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-packages

In your case as `go` is unlikey a cygwin program, you can not use the cygwin compiler to extend your `go` language. You could try the `mingw64` project

https://mingw-w64.org/

Comment: If go could be compiled for Windows, it is likely to be easier in cygwin than in mingw.  Conversely, if it builds in mingw without extra patches, it should be relatively easy in cygwin.  You can confirm it isn't included in cygwin by its absence from --enable-languages in 'gcc -v'

Comment: @tim18: "If go could be compiled for Windows." Go is compiled for Windows.

Answer (score -1):

First I would ask you if you are developing on windows or if you are only trying to compile your code for windows.

If you are developing on windows I strongly suggest installing the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" and running go in there. This will make your live a lot easier when it comes to running/compiling cgo stuff.
Note: Installing mingw is the alternative but that will make your hair go grey.

If you need to compile for windows (windows is your target system) then I suggest using [xgo](https://github.com/karalabe/xgo). It uses docker containers to compile to many different OS' in a single command.

Summary:
You can easily compile for windows without cgo, but when cgo is involved use unix for development and xgo for build (automation).

Comment: If you're using an IDE like VS Code, it want's to have gcc in the path so it can give better error reporting while you're writing code, which is super useful even if you're only really compiling in the subsystem like I do